# Sizes in rem are not scaled when I change body font-size

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

I read that sizes in rem are depending on body font-size which is root for a page. Let's see a simple example:

```
<style>
body{
font-size:16px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div style="width:10rem;height:4rem;background:green;"></div>
</body>
```

The computed width is 160px and height is 64px. It's ok.

But when I change body's `font-size` for example to `20px`, the divider is not scaled on the page to `200x80`.

Why?

Comment: you need `em` not `rem`

Comment: You need to apply the `font-size` to the `html` in your CSS, not the body. The HTML is the root element which is what you're trying to override because that's where the default 16px is coming from.

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas *body font-size which is root for a page* --> he is not right because the body is not the root